# Remove arrays in array who contain keys

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to remove arrays in array who contain specific keys.

I would like to remove arrays who contain :

```
[code] => 404
[message] => The exhibitor has no validated order.
```

Example :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2924
            [id_dossier] => 26169
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => 404
            [message] => The exhibitor has no validated order.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [code] => 404
            [message] => The exhibitor has no validated order.
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3469
            [id_dossier] => 27831

        )
)
```

And I would like output like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2924
            [id_dossier] => 26169
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3469
            [id_dossier] => 27831

        )
)
```

I tried with : `array_filter` :

```
 $final_array = array_filter($final_array, function ($var) {
        return $var['code'] != '404';
    });
```

And I tried with a `foreach` :

```
foreach ($final_array as $thisArrIndex=>$subArray) {
    if ($subArray['code'] == "404" ) {
        unset($final_array[$thisArrIndex]);
    }
}
```

My output is good but I got a notice :

**Notice :  Undefined index: code in .....**

What's wrong please ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Your notice is due to `Array( [id] => 2924, [id_dossier] => 26169)` for exemple, because it doesn't have a `code` index, you could use test `isset($var['code'])` which return `true` if `code` index exist

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where can I add this condition to know if `code` exist? I must use `unset` after ?

Comment: you can add it in `array_filter` condition, something like this : `return !isset($var['code']) || $var['code'] != '404';` and you don't need to `unset` it because these entry will be filtered by function ;)

Comment: `return ($var['code'] ?? '') != 404` You can also use the null coalescing operator if you like.